# How to get an object without undefined values?

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
let o = {
    a: 1,
    b: undefined,
    c: 2345,
    d: null
}
```

How to get an object without null and undefined values?

```
let o = {
    a: 1,
    c: 2345
}
```

Is this best practice?

```
Object.keys(o).forEach((key) => (o[key] == null || o[key] == undefined)
&& delete o[key]);
```

Comment: This seems like a fairly trivial problem. What approaches have you considered? How have they failed? Have you got as far as iterating over the properties on the object?

Comment: How are you defining "nonexistent"? `null` and `undefined` are values that (in the normal definition of things) *exist*. Are you only concerned with those values? Any value that is falsy? What about `0`? or `""`? or `"0"`? or `false`? or `[]`? or `{}`?

Comment: 0, "0", false are good values. I need to remove only nonexistent values

Comment: > null and undefined are values that (in the normal definition of things) exist... Say it to AWS Lambda function))

Comment: `delete` is almost never a best practice.

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o))` - JSON ignores undefined and null values

Comment: @Bergi It's a interesting workaround but it doesn't remove null.

Comment: @Quentin Why did you downvoted my question and all answers? Do you have an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in comment, I would suggest to avoid mutation (do not overwrite the parent variable). Consider following approach:

**Note**: `(v) => o[v]` will filter out every *falsy* value. In case, if you expect that your keys will have e.g. an empty string `''`, `0` or boolean `false` values, feel free to precise this condition.

```js
const o = {
  a: 1,
  b: undefined,
  c: 2345,
  d: null,
};

const r = Object.keys(o).filter((v) => o[v]).reduce((s, a) => ({
  ...s,
  [a]: o[a],
}), {});

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Actually empty array [] and empty object {} aren't falsy values but anyway thank you for your answer. It looks like an good answer on my bad question)

Comment: @DmitryGrinko Ah, yeah. Good spot, thanks. Anyways someone downvoted every answer, I wonder why

Answer (score 2):

Try following approach:

```
let a = {
    a: 1,
    b: undefined,
    c: 2345,
    d: null
};

for(p in a) {
  if(a[p] === undefined || a[p] === null) {
    delete a[p];
  }
}

console.log(a); // {a: 1, c: 2345}
```

UPD. Non-mutation version:

```
let result = {};
for(p in a) {
  if(a[p] === undefined || a[p] === null) {
    continue;
  }
  result[p] = a[p];
}

console.log(result); // {a: 1, c: 2345}
```

Comment: @DmitryGrinko This is a pretty common way. If you prefer ES6, then use B.K Lewis method. To satisfy ES5, use my code.

Comment: KyleRichardson said that delete will kill all optimization for that object. The hidden class becomes invalid. What do you think about it?

Comment: @DmitryGrinko I would agree with that comment... So I added non-mutation version to my answer. After getting the result, you may do an assignment `a = result` if you need to replace initial object.

Comment: @DmitryGrinko And if we are talking about performance, this try (ES5) would me much faster than `Object.keys` + `.filter` + `.reduce`.

Comment: You have to be aware that it's still mutating version. With every cycle of your `for..in` loop and passed condition, you will **mutate** the `result` variable. @KyleRichardson

Comment: Yes it mutates the "result" object, but not the original.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want for a one level deep object. It returns false, and 0 values and removes undefined and null.

```js
const o = {
  a: 1,
  b: undefined,
  c: 2345,
  d: null,
  e: 0,
  f: false,
  g: {},
  h: []
};

const r = Object.keys(o)
  .filter((v) => {
    return o[v] === false || o[v] === 0 || o[v];
  })
  .reduce((s, a) => ({
    ...s,
    [a]: o[a],
  }),
{});

console.log(r);
```

Comment: @Kinduser I was only trying to help him, if you look at comments I told him to accept your answer, because this is your answer plus helping him include false and 0 values. Not trying to take credit :)

Comment: Sure, it's fine :P

Answer (score 0):

Can do something quite easy such as:

```
Object.keys(o).forEach((key) => (o[key] == null || o[key] == undefined)
&& delete o[key]);
```

This will remove all null and undefined values.

Comment: I did something like this. Is it best practice?

Comment: @DmitryGrinko I would say it's the simplest way and definitely efficient enough for what you're doing. I think people could argue against it being the 'best' way but I do things like this 9 times out of 10.

Comment: @DmitryGrinko neither do I my friend

Comment: @B.KLewis The `delete` operator is not efficient at all

Comment: I would suggest to avoid mutation.

Comment: @Kinduser What do you mean?

Comment: @Bergi A link to your source for that claim and a different work around would be helpful

Comment: @B.K Lewis  Read about v8 and hidden class optimization. `delete` will kill all optimization for that object. The hidden class becomes invalid.

Comment: @KyleRichardson Do you have any answer on my question?

Comment: @DmitryGrinko I up voted Kind User's answer. It is the solution I would suggest. Just keep in mind this will only work for one level of the object. Nested objects will not have undefined and null values removed. You will need to use this recursively on nested objects. Also as stated, this will remove 0 and boolean false as well, so adjust to keep those values as needed.

Comment: @KyleRichardson Thank you. I agree with you but actually I don't care about nested objects and such values as 0 and false are important in my case. And answer of dhilt looks very good as well.

Comment: @DmitryGrinko I would not use `delete` personally.

Comment: @KyleRichardson Yes. I mean his Non-mutation version

Comment: @DmitryGrinko posted answer that does what you want. You should accept King User's answer though, imo.